# What is realistic minimum possible size, weight and power output of an atomic battery for 100kWh?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

AFAIK atomic batteries could become a single unit nuclear reactor, but what it is smallest feasible configuration by our current knowledge? (even at conceptual design level)

Comment: Way too broad. But, as a total spitball, the size is limited first by the density of potential energy - i.e. what isotope in what form, then by how to interact with the released energy, then by how to make that released energy useful. You could make a very small beta-battery - you just might not get much power out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reality check: 2 meter height for 1kWh.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilopower